# Novel about a great swordsman who died and became an orphan boy

Tags: story-identification, novel, sword-and-sorcery

I don't really remember a whole lot about this novel. It's like this...A great swordsman, who is like really good, was killed or died because he was deemed a traitor. And then the novel goes to this remote village and features about this merchant who visited the village and found a orphan boy, who taught other orphans on the street how to count and other stuff. AND, like any other story, the merchant became 'interested' with the orphan boy.

Comment: Any fantasy elements in the story?

Comment: @chiwa - Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this novel, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, to be clear, was the swordsman _reincarnated_ as the orphaned boy?

Comment: About 4 years ago, in 2018.